# Why this script won't get every 5 character line from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to get every 5 character word from my text file, in the text file, every word is new line. This script gets almost every word, but some of them are left out, in this scenario word 'marka' is in text file by isn't getting saved by my script, can you help me to understand why?

```
slowa = []

with open('slowa.txt', encoding='utf-8') as words:
    for i in words:
        lines = words.readline()
        if len(lines) == 6:
            slowa.append(lines)
            print(lines)

print('marka' in slowa)

with open('slowa5.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as slowa5:
    for i in slowa:
        #slowa5.write('\n')
        slowa5.write(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already iterating over the lines in the `for` loop, so calling `readline()` causes every other line to be skipped. Just directly use the variable `i` which stores the current line.

```py
with open('slowa.txt', encoding='utf-8') as words:
    for i in words:
        if len(i) == 6:
            slowa.append(i)
            print(i)
```